# How to limit recursion depending on node and relationship properties for each connected node pair

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's start from simple query that finds all coworkers recursively.

```
match (user:User {username: 'John'})
match (user)-[:WORKED_WITH *1..]-(coworkers:User)
return user, coworkers
```

Now, I have to modify it in order to recieve only those users, that are connected with first `N` relationships.

Every `User` label have value of `N` in the properties, and every relationship have date of creation in its properties.

*I suppose, that it can be reasonable to create and maintain separate set of relationships that will satisfy this condition.*

---

**UPD:** Limitations have to be applied only for those, who know each other directly.

Limitation have to be applied to each node in the path, e.g. first user have 3 relationships `:WORKED_WITH` (on the first level) and limitation 5, than everything OK we can continue to check connected users, if user have 6 relationships and limitation 5, only 5 of relationships have to be used to move on.

*I understand that it can be slow query, but how to do that without hand written tools? One of improvements is to move all that limitations out of query execution into some preprocessing step and create additional type of relationships that will hold all of those limitations, it will require validations because they are not part of the state but projection of the state.*

Answer (score 1):

The following query should work (as long as you do not have a lot of data). It uses `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

```
MATCH (user:User {username: 'John'})-[:WORKED_WITH*]-(coworker:User)
WITH DISTINCT user, coworker
ORDER BY coworker.createDate
RETURN COLLECT(coworker)[0..user.N] AS coworkers;
```

Note: since variable-length paths have exponential complexity, you would usually want to specify a reasonable upper bound (e.g., `[:WORKED_WITH*..5]`) to avoid the query running too long or causing an out-of-memory error. Also, since the `LIMIT` operator does not accept a variable as its argument, this query uses `COLLECT(coworker)[0..user.N]` to get the `N` coworkers with the earliest `createDate` -- which is also a bit expensive.

---

Now, if (as you suggested) you had created a specific type of relationship (e.g., `FIRST_WORKED_WITH`) between each `User` and its `N` earliest "coworkers", that would allow you to use the following trivial and fast query:

```
MATCH (user:User {username: 'John'})-[:FIRST_WORKED_WITH]->(coworker:User)
RETURN coworker;
```

Comment: I have added additional explanation. Limitations should be applied only for those who know each other directly.

Comment: Is there a way to limit execution by time? If there are a lot of connections, BFS will take care only about closest connections, if there are few connections per node, than it will go deeper?